# Login ASP.NET con Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-19c

Quiero hacer un login para mi página web que consuma un procedimiento almacenado en una base de datos Oracle 19c pero me da el siguiente error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Operación no válida dado el estado
> actual del objeto.'

He intentado de todo, y no funciona, además, las credenciales son correctas ya que el email es **a@juan.com**  y el número de documento es **1**

La tabla en Oracle es:

```
CREATE TABLE LA_Usuario(
    ID_Usu_NumeroDocumento INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Usu_NombreCompleto VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Usu_TipoDoc VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Usu_TelefonoResidencial INT NOT NULL,
    Usu_TelefonoMovil INT NOT NULL,
    Dir_ID INT,
    Usu_Direccion VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    Usu_Email VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    Rol_ID INT,
    Usu_Estado INT   
);
```

El procedimiento:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE INGRESO_USUARIO
(
    usu_email varchar,
    id_usu_numerodocumento int
)
AS
    usuEmail VARCHAR(50);
    usuNumeroDoc INT;
BEGIN
    SELECT usu_email, id_usu_numerodocumento INTO usuEmail,usuNumeroDoc  FROM LA_USUARIO WHERE usu_email = usu_email AND id_usu_numerodocumento = id_usu_numerodocumento;
END;
```

El código de C# para consumir (o enviar parámetros) al procedimiento:

```
            OracleConnection conexion = new OracleConnection(con);
            conexion.Open();
            OracleCommand com = new OracleCommand();
            com.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.CommandText = "INGRESO_USUARIO";
            com.Parameters.Add("usu_email", correoElectronico.Text);
            com.Parameters.Add("id_usu_numerodocumento", Convert.ToInt32(numeroDocumento.Text));

            OracleDataReader lector = com.ExecuteReader();

            if (lector.Read())
            {
                Response.Redirect("admin/dashboard.aspx");
                conexion.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("ingreso.aspx");
                conexion.Close();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Los procedures, no regresan ningún tipo de respuesta, te será imposible comunicarle a C# el resultado.

Tal vez sea mejor q utilices una función en su lugar , y devuelvas verdadero o falso en base a la query.

También te recomiendo que hagas uso de manejo de excepciones en PLSQL para el caso en que no encuentre la información

Comment: ¿Cómo podría usar una función booleana en el procedure para que devuelva el dato?, saludos.